# How to JOIN two table in BigQuery, but the join parameter are nested

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

sorry for the newbie questions, just started learning SQL. I have two tables:

1. sessions
2. items

`sessions` table has `questions` (RECORD, Repeated), and inside `questions` there's `item_id` (String)

`items` table has `topics` (RECORD, Repeated), and inside `topics` there's `prior_difficulty` (String). `items` table also has `item_id` (String)

My objective is to get a list of sessions and its prior_difficulty, by joining the two tables with their `item_id`. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first use the `unnest()` function to retrieve all the `item_id`s from the sessions table and then join them with the `item_id` from the items table.
To retrieve the `prior_difficulty` from your struct column `topics`, you can also use the `unnest()` function :

```sql
select distinct
  sessions.session_id,
  t.prior_difficulty
from sessions, unnest(questions) q
left join items on q.item_id = items.item_id, unnest(topics) t
```

or if you want to create a repeated record column to group `prior_difficulty` values by `session_id` :

```sql
select
  sessions.session_id,
  array_agg(distinct t.prior_difficulty ignore nulls) as prior_difficulties
from sessions, unnest(questions) q
left join items on q.item_id = items.item_id, unnest(topics) t
group by 1
```

Comment: thank you so much!
it works for my case. really sorry I can't give a vote because my reputation is 0